# Azure Cloud publish issue with Server Error

Tags: azure, cloud, publish, server-error

I just published my ASP.Net website on azure through Visual Studio, and it directs me to my site, and it gives me the error RESOURCE NOT FOUND HTTP 404....but when i enter mysite.azurewebsites.net/index.html it gives me my site...how do I fix this?

Comment: Have you set "index.html" as the default page? You can do so in the portal.

Comment: how is it done? I'm trying to evaluate the trial version, so I could use guidance @GauravMantri

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set up the default document in Application Settings. Assuming you are using App Services that is.

Comment: I'm using trial account, trying out the azure, so I am still not very informed on how to change the default document, can You help out?

Answer (score 0):

I successfuly changed the name of the desired home page, in my case `index.html`, to `default.html`...I solved my problem with a little help from my commentators. Tnx